# Java method override - parent method is called when a parameter is used

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

Here is the code I wrote:

https://pastebin.com/raw/0iBrGJR4

Most relevant parts:

```
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();    

    System.out.println(((A) b).a());    
    System.out.println(((A) b).b(3));    


  static class A {
    Object a() {
      System.out.println("A.a()");
    }

    Object b(Number x) {
      System.out.println("A.b()");    
    }
  }


  static class B extends A {
    String a() {
      System.out.println("B.a()");
      return "hello";
    }

    String b(Integer x) {
      System.out.println("B.b()");
      return "hola" + x;
    }
  }
```

When I run this, the first print displays

```
B.a()
hello
```

which is what I expected, since even though we cast to A, the call goes through to the object's actual type which is B.

But the second print, the ((A) b).b(3) call, prints

```
A.b()
3
```

(i.e. it calls the method in A). Force casting 3 to Integer doesn't do anything either. Can someone explain this behavior to me? I don't understand what the reason is. I would've expected ((A) b).b(3) to print `B.() \n hola3` rather than use the parent class method.

Comment: to print what you are expecting you need to use b.b(3) because as you are casting ((A) b).b(3) Class A it uses the method of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, what makes a method override another method in a parent class is if it has the same name but different number and/or types of arguments.

In your case class `A` has a method `b(Number x)` and class `B` that extends `A` has a method `b(Integer x)` ==> `B.b()` doesn't override `A.b()` ==> when executing `((A) b).b(b)`, `A.b(3)` is executed.

On the contrary, `B.a()` **does override** `A.a()` ==> when executing `((A) b).a()`, `B.a()` is executed.

The **return value** of the methods doesn't matter when overriding, only name and arguments.